# The border-right of a button disappears when resizing the window on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm struggling with a Chrome-specific bug. Sometimes, when resizing the window, the border of a button will disappear. I'm sorry, I can't provide a minimal and reproducible example even though I tried to reproduce the bug on a separate document.

I'm hoping that's a known bug and that there is a fix for it. I've tried the following solutions already, without success:

- [Fix for Chrome not rendering 1px borders - MuffinMan](https://muffinman.io/blog/fix-for-chrome-not-rendering-borders/)
- [Bug? Chrome 62.0.3202.62 1px borders disappear at some scales. - Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0r1neUxqo5Gc/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fchrome%2Fr1neUxqo5Gc)

[image: gif of the bug]

Configuration:

- Chrome 92.0.4515.159